# Clear call notification on call receiver

Tags: java, android

I have a receiver for incoming calls , i want to clear call notification when broadcast received , how should i do?

```
public class IncommingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) 
    {
        //some method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel notification using a id

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
notificationManager.cancel(id);
```

Create a id when you create the notification

```
  // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

Comment: Thanks for post.but i don't know what is the call notification id?